# How to inflate the size of drawn rectangle throught a for-loop in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, for-loop, drawrectangle

I cannot inflate the original drawn rectangle through for-loop.
I wanted to maybe store the original drawn rectangle into an array and from their loop it, but it did not work properly.

```
 loop_txtbx.Text = 5
 parameter_txtbx.Text = 20

 int[] rec = new int[loops];

 int xCenter = Convert.ToInt32(startX_coord_txtbx.Text);
 int yCenter = Convert.ToInt32(startY_coord_txtbx.Text); 

 int width = Convert.ToInt32(width_txtbx.Text);
 int height = Convert.ToInt32(height_txtbx.Text);

 //Find the x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.
  int x = xCenter - width / 2;

 //Find y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw. 
  int y = yCenter - height / 2;

  int loops = Convert.ToInt32(loop_txtbx.Text);
  int param = Convert.ToInt32(parameter_txtbx.Text);

   // Create a rectangle.
  Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

   // Draw the uninflated rectangle to screen.
  gdrawArea.DrawRectangle(color_pen, rec1);   

  for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
      {

      // Call Inflate.
      Rectangle rec2 = Rectangle.Inflate(rec1, param, param);

      // Draw the inflated rectangle to screen.
      gdrawArea.DrawRectangle(color_pen, rec2);
      }
```

Only 2 drawn rectangles are shown, while it was supposed to be 5. I cannot manage to modify rec2

Comment: You are creating `rec2` based on the same `rec1`, every time around the loop.  Either `rec1 = rec2` in the loop or just inflate `rec1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same rec1 as a base to inflate. So after the first loop you get always the same size for the new rectangle.

You need to use rec2

```
Rectangle rec2 = rec1;
for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
{
    rec2 = Rectangle.Inflate(rec2, param, param);
    ....
}
```

But with this approach you should invert the order of the calls to draw the initial rectangle

```
  Rectangle rec2 = rec1;
  for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
  {
       // Draw the current rectangle to screen.
       gdrawArea.DrawRectangle(color_pen, rec2);

       // Call Inflate.
       rec2 = Rectangle.Inflate(rec2, param, param);
  }
```

Comment: thanks, i was wondering the same thing but I wasnt sure how to properly do it.

Comment: And perhaps we should also invert the order of the calls. First draw the rectangle then inflate it